# Why am I getting PLS-00103 when I try to create a table in a PL/SQL procedure?

Tags: oracle, plsql, ddl

I am getting this error:

`[Error] PLS-00103 (23: 9): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CREATE" when expecting one of the following:
   begin case declare exit for goto if loop mod null pragma
   raise return select update while with <an identifier>`

when attempting to run this code. What is it that I'm doing wrong here?
Should I use bulk collect. if so, how?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE P_CLEAN_LICENSEE_ARCHIVE AS
BEGIN
    /*******************************************************************/
    /* This is an array of IDs for licensees                           */
    /*******************************************************************/
   array_l := l_arr(1026679, 1026714, 1036991, 1026735, 1026715, 1159363, 1026703, 1169002, 1052762, 1070152, 1026684, 
                    1026685, 1164376, 1026693, 1026733, 1026698, 1026701, 1026680, 1026708, 1026710, 1026688, 1026697, 
                    1026690, 1026691, 1026692, 1099236, 1026694, 1099235, 1026734, 1026700, 1026682, 1026683, 1099142, 
                    1026687, 1026689, 1026732, 1026699, 1047967, 1026702, 1026704, 1026711, 1026712, 1026713, 1026681, 
                    1108357, 1175754, 1079806, 1099275, 1026709, 1099281, 1099282, 1208557, 1175755, 1194482, 1112569);

    /*******************************************************************/
    /* Loop through the IDs and do the work                            */
    /*******************************************************************/
    FOR i IN array_l.FIRST .. array_l.LAST
    LOOP
        /*******************************************************************/
        /* The following SQL retrieves the fkp_fd_rid from all the records */
        /* in the archive modified more than one year ago for the passed   */ 
        /* CLI_RID, builds a temp table with the fd_rids for use to delete */
        /* the records.                                                    */
        /*******************************************************************/
        CREATE TABLE fd_rid AS 
            SELECT fd.* FROM filedirectory fd 
            WHERE fd.FD_RID IN (SELECT fkp.fkp_fd_rid FROM filekeypair fkp 
                                WHERE fkp.fkp_keyword = 'CLI_RID' 
                                  AND fkp.fkp_value = TO_CHAR(array_l(i))) 
              AND fd.FD_LASTMODIFIED < SYSDATE-365;

        /*******************************************************************/
        /* This code then deletes the records from both filekeypair and    */
        /* filedirectory.                                                  */       
        /*******************************************************************/
        DELETE FROM filekeypair WHERE fkp_fd_rid IN (SELECT * FROM fd_rid);
        COMMIT;
        DELETE FROM filedirectory WHERE fd_rid IN (SELECT * FROM fd_rid);
        COMMIT;
        /*******************************************************************/
        /* Now drop the temp table.                                        */       
        /*******************************************************************/
        DROP TABLE fd_rid;
        COMMIT;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can not write DDL in PL/SQL block directly as you have shown in your question.

However you can execute these DDLs using `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` command as demonstrated below.

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ddl_test AS
  BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE tbl1';
  END;
  /
```